# Java final variable in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I am curious about, what is the equivalent of final tag in delphi :

```
 public final int stackoverflow;
```

I use

> class var

tag but class var equals static variable. But final is different from them.

Comment: Delphi only supports constants which are initialized at compile time. So a `public final int someNumber = 42` would be `public const someNumber: Integer = 42` in Delphi.

Comment: Looks like a singleton to me. So to imitate the final behaviour in Delphi you would need to construct a singleton.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Java final variable can be initialized once only. This initialization can be made by an initialization statement, or by an assignment statement.

As such there is not equivalent in Delphi. There is nothing that allows you to restrict a variable to being initialized no more than one time. The closest equivalent would be a constant, declared with `const`. This would restrict you to making the initialization in the `const` declaration.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing comparable shipped with delphi.

But you can achieve this with a record

```
unit FinalType;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils;

type
  Final<T> = record
  private
    FIsInitialized: string;
    FValue: T;
  public
    class operator implicit( const a: T ): Final<T>;
    class operator implicit( const a: Final<T> ): T;
  end;

implementation

{ Final<T> }

class operator Final<T>.implicit( const a: T ): Final<T>;
begin
  if Result.FIsInitialized <> ''
  then
    raise Exception.Create( 'Fehlermeldung' );

  Result.FIsInitialized := '*';
  Result.FValue := a;
end;

class operator Final<T>.implicit( const a: Final<T> ): T;
begin
  if a.FIsInitialized = ''
  then
    Result := default ( T )
  else
    Result := a.FValue;
end;

end.
```

---

```
program FinalCheck;

uses
  FinalType;

var
  MyFinalValue : Final<Integer>;

procedure OutputValue( AValue : Integer );
begin
  WriteLn( 'Value: ', AValue );
end;

begin
  MyFinalValue := 10; // everything is ok
  OutputValue( MyFinalValue );
  MyFinalValue := 12; // <- Exception
  OutputValue( MyFinalValue );
end.
```

---

**UPDATE**

There is one side effect you cannot catch:

```
program FinalCheck;

uses
  FinalType;

var
  MyFinalValue : Final<Integer>;

procedure SetFinalValue( AValue : Integer );
var
  LNewValue : Final<Integer>;
begin
  LNewValue := AValue;
  MyFinalValue := LNewValue;
end;

begin
  MyFinalValue := 10; // everything is ok
  SetFinalValue( 12 ); // no exception!!!
end.
```

---

In most cases I see this as a public ReadOnly field of a class. In Delphi you would use a public readonly property instead, but you have to take care, that the value is not changed from inside the class. The final flag ist just a guard, that you cannot change the value from inside.

This is a class with a final - but it is only final with the comment and if you respect this

```
TFoo = class
private
  // Please do not change this value once it is set
  FStackoverflow : Integer;
public
  property Stackoverflow : Integer read FStackoverflow;
end;
```

Or with the record

```
TFoo = class
public
  Stackoverflow : Final<Integer>;
end;
```

Comment: I was just about to post something essentially identical.  Have to be careful with the generic implementation in the case of reference types.  Curious why a string for `FIsInitialized`... surely a boolean makes more sense?  Might also make `Final<T>`'s fields `strict private` to enforce the criticality of those fields as being strictly private for this to not break.

Comment: @J... A boolean is senseless here. All *reference counted* types are preinitialized with the default value. So I can rely on that `FIsInitialized : string` will always be empty, because `string` is a reference counted type. A boolean can have any value, because it is not being initialized.

Comment: Ah, surely... of course.  Wasn't thinking.  Once records start getting smart enough I forget they're not classes.  Doubly confounded by testing in the console with a global var (that is initialized).

Comment: It's surely worth stating that whilst you *can* do this, nobody ever would.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I would use in this situation *always* a public read only property with a comment.

Comment: Yes, I think that is the best option

Comment: A Java compiler runs a flow analysis to ensure that, for every assignment to a blank final variable, the variable is definitely unassigned before the assignment; otherwise a compile-time error occurs. Such a compile-time check does not happen in Delphi, re-assignments lead to a run-time error - too late to fix the code :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `const` keyword in Delphi

```
 Const MAX_LINES = 3;
```

Note that you could never change the value during the application running

Comment: Please note that you can have writable constants with the `{$J+}` or `{$WRITEABLECONST ON}` directive

Comment: @whosrdaddy - only for *typed* constants, eg: `Const MAX_LINES: Integer = 3`